# Is it possible to change the keybindings in MuPDF?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, mupdf

The default keybindings are listed in the [MuPDF manual](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mupdf-gl.html), but is there a way to remap any of the shortcuts (on Windows)?

Comment: I can't answer your question since you're running Windows, but changing the default keybindings is a rather trivial task for the OpenGL version of mupdf, so if you happen to use that specific platform, then the keybindings can be modified in `mupdf/platform/gl/gl-main.c` (assuming you have cloned the repository) in the function `static void do_app(void)`.